# How soon can a let's encrypt certificate be successfully renewed?

Tags: lets-encrypt

Figured a simple Google search will have the answer on top but apparently I can't find it.

I understand one can try let's encrypt renewal every day without penalty but what is the soonest a certificate can be successfully renewed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, it's set to renew if the expiration is within 30 days.

https://github.com/certbot/certbot/blob/e048da1e389ede7a52bd518ab4ebf9a0b18bfafc/certbot/certbot/_internal/constants.py#L141

You can configure this by changing the `renew_before_expiry` value in the config.

Comment: thanks but that's certbot specific. i'm specifically referring to a renewal request sent to let's encrypt via any app. how close to expiration can the cert be before let's encrypt renews the cert? or does it even care? for example does it successfully renew a cert if requested every day?

Comment: If you're making your own client, looks like it'd hit rate limits at once a day, but only barely. https://letsencrypt.org/docs/rate-limits/ "Renewals are treated specially: they don’t count against your Certificates per Registered Domain limit, but they are subject to a Duplicate Certificate limit of 5 per week."

Comment: think that's the ticket. so seems like the cert's age or exp. date is irrelevant and 5 renewals per week is the limit. and i believe one can use up the 5 renewals within any given period. be it all in an hour or the span of a week.

Comment: @rvh That's my reading as well. I can't claim to have tested it, though. :-)